# Code returns undefined instead of the result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a certain form to return how many numbers are bigger than 10 from a certain input given from the user. This needs to run in the same page as another from that runs another function.

The second function, "mare" returns undefined, whilst the first one works okay. Should there be a way to store the input in a an array and then pass the function on it?

I'm a rookie so any other recommendations or tips and tricks are welcome.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var val = '';
  var contor = 0;

  function multiplu(j) {
    return j % 3 == 0 || j % 7 == 0;
  }

  function mare(input) {
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if (input[i] > 10) {
        return contor++;
      };
    }
  };

  $('#newItem').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#unu').append('<li>' + this.value + ': ' +
        multiplu(this.value) + "</li>");
    }
  });

  $('#newItem2').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#doi').append('<li> din sirul ' + this.value + 'sunt: ' +
        mare(this.value) + " mai mari ca 10 </li>");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="newItem">
<input type="text" id="newItem2">
<div id="prnt">
  <ul id="unu">
    <li>potato</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="prnt">
  <ul id="doi">
    <li>potato</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `mare()` function doesn't have a return statement if it doesn't fit the criteria of `input[i] > 10`, so it returns undefined (also, it will never fit this criteria)

Comment: The issue is because the `input` argument in the `mare()` function is a string. Accessing a string by index gets you the *single* character at that index. Therefore a single character cannot possibly match the `> 10` condition (assuming both values are of the same type, which is another potential issue). What exactly is the logic you're trying to create?

Comment: What does it mean 'how many numbers are bigger than 10' if you are dealing with input value? What you expect for value 77 for example?

Comment: there is an exercise that i found online that says that i have to create a function that counts the numbers from a certain array that are bigger than 10. I wanted to make this work with any series of numbers that an user could input

Comment: So, in this case you should define a separator and then split you input by this separator. Let me try to show it

Answer (score 0):

You want to get how many numbers are bigger than 10 from number of inputs then you can assign some `class` to those inputs, for example `item`.

Then use jquery to find all inputs which have class by `$('.item').toArray()`.

You can filter those inputs and select only those which have value greater than 10 with `.filter(x => x.value > 10)`.

Then simply get `.length` which will return total number of such inputs.

**You can check complete code below.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var val = '';
  var contor = 0;

  function multiplu(j) {
    return j % 3 == 0 || j % 7 == 0;
  }

  function mare() {
    return $('.item').toArray().filter(x => x.value > 10).length;
  };

  $('#newItem').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#unu').append('<li>' + this.value + ': ' +
        multiplu(this.value) + "</li>");
    }
  });

  $('#newItem2').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#doi').append('<li> din sirul ' + this.value + 'sunt: ' +
        mare() + " mai mari ca 10 </li>");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="item" id="newItem">
<input type="text" class="item" id="newItem2">
<div id="prnt">
  <ul id="unu">
    <li>potato</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="prnt">
  <ul id="doi">
    <li>potato</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comment you should define separator(I defined it as `,`). Then on enter press you should split your input string by this separator and then iterate over this array and check which numbers are greater than 10. Here an example:

```js
var val = '';

function multiplu(j) {
  return j % 3 == 0 || j % 7 == 0;
}

function mare(input) {
  var contor = 0;
  const splitted = input.split(',');

  splitted.forEach(function(value) {
    if (+value > 10) {
      ++contor;
    }
  });

  return contor;
};

$('#newItem').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#unu').append('<li>' + this.value + ': ' +
      multiplu(this.value) + "</li>");
  }
});

$('#newItem2').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#doi').append('<li> din sirul ' + this.value + ' sunt: ' +
      mare($(this).val()) + " mai mari ca 10 </li>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="newItem">
<input type="text" id="newItem2">
<div id="prnt">
  <ul id="unu">
    <li>potato</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="prnt">
  <ul id="doi">
    <li>potato</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```